# hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Error: User.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

this error has came out from my code
I can't find the reason...

I made a model by using 'extends Model'
so it should be the subclass of Model

user.ts

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { dbType } from "./index";
import { sequelize } from "./sequelize";

export class User extends Model {
  public readonly id!: string;
  public email!: string;
  public password!: string;
  public salt!: string;
  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    salt: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(29),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    modelName: "User",
    tableName: "User",
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    updatedAt: "updateTimestamp",
  }
);

export const associate = (db: dbType) => {
  db.User.hasMany(db.Word, { as: "words", foreignKey: "id" });
};
```

word.ts

```
import { DataTypes, Model, Association } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "./index";
import { dbType } from "./index";
import { User } from "./user";

// These are all the attributes in the Word model
interface WordAttributes {
  wordId: string;
  owner: string;
  name: string;
  meaning: string[];
  tags: string[];
}

export class Word extends Model<WordAttributes> {
  public readonly wordId!: string;
  public name!: string;
  public meaning!: string[];
  public tags!: string[];
  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

  public static associations: {
    wordBelongsToUser: Association<User, Word>;
  };
}

Word.init(
  {
    wordId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    owner: {
      type: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    meaning: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      allowNull: true,
    },
    tags: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    modelName: "Word",
    tableName: "Word",
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    updatedAt: "updateTimestamp",
  }
);

export const associate = (db: dbType) => {
  db.Word.belongsTo(db.User, { as: "Owner", foreignKey: "id" });
};
```

index.ts

```
import { User, associate as associateUser } from "./user";
import { Word, associate as associateWord } from "./word";

export * from "./sequelize";
const db = {
  User,
  Word,
};

associateUser(db);
associateWord(db);

export type dbType = typeof db;
```

I wanna know the reason why does it happened
I made a model by using extends